# How to scroll screen in android native app having recyclerview using appium

Tags: java, appium-android

I am trying to automate an app which is built using recyclerview. There are totally 10 tiles and in one screen 1st four tiles will be visible and to get other tiles I need to move the screen upward. I tried to move the screen by finding co-ordinates and "(AndroidElement)driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceIdMatches(\".*id/type_text\")).setMaxSearchSwipes(5).scrollIntoView("new UiSelector().text(\"" + text + "\"))"))" this but there is slightly movement in the screen and couldn't get the remaining tiles. Is there any way to scroll to the bottom of the screen so that I can get last tile also.

Comment: Can you specific or change the coordinates using actions ? It should work well.

Comment: @john, I tried the code given in [this] (https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-scroll-on-android-without-using-coordinates/8301/5) . I just replaced drive.swipe() using TouchAction class. But still I am not able to scroll. If you can, please give me some sample code what exactly you are trying to tell.

Comment: swipe is has been deprecated for a while unless you are using older java-client

Comment: Read this Raju : 
https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sammar Ahmad, yes you were right. I was using wrong element. I constantly tried and finally worked after using co-ordinates.Code looks something like below. Created scroll() in homepage class and called the same from my test class

```
public void scroll(int x, int y) {
    int startY = (int) (driver.manage().window().getSize().getHeight() * 0.90);
    int endY = (int) (driver.manage().window().getSize().getHeight() * 0.10);
    TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
    action.press(point(x, startY)).waitAction(waitOptions(ofSeconds(3))).moveTo(point(x, endY)).release().perform();
}

MobileElement startElement = (MobileElement) driver.findElementById("mention parent element here");
Point location = startElement.getLocation();
    homepage.scroll(location.x,location.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. I think there's some issue in your UiScrollable..

```
MobileElement listItem=(MobileElement)driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()"
                  + ".scrollable(true)).scrollIntoView("
                  + "new UiSelector().text(\"<Mention your element text value here>\"))"));
```

Comment: I tried you code but still I am not able to scroll the page until i can see my required element

Comment: This scrollable actually works like it scrolls down if the element is not found then it randomly scrolls either upside or downside. So there's no specific order. But it scrolls in both direction until the element is not found. It is perfectly working in my app.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Its randomly scrolling upside and downside but there is only slight movement in the screen.

Comment: The screen scrolls randomly in upside and downside and after some time I get the below error.   
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

Comment: I think the issue may be in the element locator. You might be mentioning wrong value of the element.

Answer (score 0):

```
MobileElement listItem=(MobileElement)driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(\"<Mention your element text value here>\"))"));
```

You can modify @sammar's code like this to scroll to the element.